# Designable build failed: Could not attach to pid : "26000"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I can't figure out a problem with a view that I have created (xib + swift file) with setup, init and prepareForInterfaceBuilder func. I try to show it in a scene with @IBDesignable.

When I try these sames files in a new project everything works fine.
But in my main project with 4 targets it doesn't work (I checked all target membership in all files but the problem is not that).

When I try to selected my view in the storyboard with inherits from my **@IBDesignable** view and tap **Editor -> Debug Selected Views** the only error that I have it this one:

**Could not attach to pid : “xxxx” | Error 1** (the number change every time i try the step before).

In the "Show the report navigator" in Interface Builder section I only have this error:

> Showing Recent Errors Only
>   :-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/Utilisateur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyMainProjectName-hdyurngtrorjbdfvmlaynduhfjye/Build/Intermediates.noindex/IBDesignables/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyMainProjectNameProd.app/Info.plist':
>   1) Target 'MyMainProjectNameProd' (project 'MyMainProjectName') has copy command from '/Users/Utilisateur/Documents/Dev/JohnPaul/iOS/myMainProjectName-ios/MyMainProjectName/Environments/Prod/Info.plist' to '/Users/Utilisateur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyMainProjectName-hdyurngtrorjbdfvmlaynduhfjye/Build/Intermediates.noindex/IBDesignables/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyMainProjectNameProd.app/Info.plist'
>   2) Target 'MyMainProjectNameProd' (project 'MyMainProjectName') has process command with output '/Users/Utilisateur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyMainProjectName-hdyurngtrorjbdfvmlaynduhfjye/Build/Intermediates.noindex/IBDesignables/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyMainProjectNameProd.app/Info.plist'

I don't know what to try now because already tried to:
 - delete derivedData
 - restart Xcode
 - restart my macbook
 - unselect /reselect target membership
 - remove / readd files to project
 - check/uncheck Debug executable
 - search logs in System Reports but nothing...

Here are the two files if you want to try and see the code:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-MIacqvQNEGJdPOHgfQIaT_ZlmCk1WAb

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

1. First I had to check in 'Build Phases' tab of each targets that the Info.plist was in the list.

[image]

Double check if the membership of each Info.plist has his target checked.

[image]

2. Then I had to switch the Build system to "Legacy Build system" one in File top tab of Xcode > Workspace settings... > Build System dropdown and tape Done button

[image]

3. Then I had to go in the storyboard when I want to show my xib view implemented dans tap "Refresh All Views" button.

[image]

4. Finally after few seconds of loading I was able to see my xib in my viewcontroller scene.

[image]

Hope this answer will help.

Thanks.

Comment: Info.plist cannot have any membership checked.